# Animations stopped functioning after upgrade to Angular 15

Tags: angular

I've read through the Angular animations docs and of course the breaking changes for Angular 15 but cannot see why my animations have stopped working.

> @keyframes name format changes
> In v15, @keyframes names are prefixed with the component's scope name. PR #42608
>
> For example, in a component definition whose scope name is host-my-cmp, a @keyframes rule with a name in v14 of:
>
> @keyframes foo { ... }
> becomes in v15:
>
> @keyframes host-my-cmp_foo { ... }

What does this refer to?

Here is the animation code I have and it seems to be the same setup as in [Keyframes](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#keyframes-name-format-changes) and [Animation](https://angular.io/api/animations/keyframes) docs.

```
@Component({
    ...
    animations: [routerAnimation()] <-- no use of keyframes
})

// view
<div class="ro-wrapper" [@routerAnimation]="getRouteAnimation(router)">
    <router-outlet #router="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

What am I missing about this breaking change?

Comment: Please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, currently, animation code is not shared also!

Comment: It's indeed hard to say what is happening without a StackBlitz. However I can explain the keyframes change: Previously, all keyframes would "leak" between your components, even if you asked for `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. With the new renaming support, keyframes no longer leak (unless you set `ViewEncapsulation.None`). This should not affect you unless you are defining keyframes outside a component, and referring to them inside of it.

Comment: Thank you @dylhunn that makes more sense. I didnt include all the code because it is fully functional on Angular 14. Even switching branches back and forth shows that only bumping the Angular versions cause it to stop.

Comment: We also have this problem. our keyframes ARE defined inside our components. So from what I read, we should not be affected. And yet, a large number of our animations did stop working.

Comment: Did you find out the cause @BenRacicot

Comment: @O'Rooney I did not. I had to curb the issue and after many updates it seems to have resumed working. It was certainly an issue as you’re confirming. If you find the cause please write an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be this Angular bug:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49378

Basically, the angular processing that is supposed to put the component scope name as a prefix on both animation-name and the @keyframes rule, doesn't find things inside media queries and therefore they may not match.

That's what's causing it for us.

The workaround we are using is to change to using &[is-mobile] type of rules instead of media queries, and providing properties in the typescript